# MATLAB: find whether the specific index in the correspondinig column

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, find

The problem is as follow:

I have a **k-nearest** `index` matrix. The column of the matrix denotes the number of an image (1:n). The row of `index` matrix denotes the index of **k-nearest** pixels correspoinding to the query pixel.

So I am using for-loops to find out whether `a`-th index is in column `b`: for example, `3` is in the first column (`1`-th pixel), then find out whether `1` is in `3`-th column, if no, assign value, if yes, assign another value.

The code is here:

```
for pix = 1:row*col
    for i = 1:k
        position = find(Index(:, Index(i,pix)) == pix);
        if isempty(position) difference =  - weight(k, Index(i,pix)) ;
        else difference =  weight(i,pix) - weight(position, Index(i,pix)) ; end
    end
end
```

Since `row*col` is very large. I hope to reduce the code into one for-loop. Is there any other method to speed up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This explanation is pretty dense to understand, a [mcve] would help demonstrate your expected input and outputs

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for your advice, I just revise.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that makes things slightly clearer. Sorry if I wasn't clear, for reference a [mcve] should include a small example which is self-contained, so that we can run it and see the outputs vs the expected outputs, and what might be going wrong. Since we have no clear example for `Index` or `weight`, this makes answering harder.